# How to edit VBA to accomodate larger UBound Array

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am a super beginner to VBA and I was attempting to create a macro that would identify negative word/phrase keywords and comment on them in a Word document. I found a VBA script on Stackoverflow and replaced their keywords with my own, which worked. However at some point it no longer lets me add more keywords (I think it stopped letting me type after 100). Could someone please take a look at this and give me a solution as to how I can continue to add more keywords? Would you do something like create a new `Dim (keywords2) As String` and somehow loop through both? Thanks in advance!

Here's the code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FindNegativeWordPhraseMacro()
    Dim myDoc As Document
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Set myDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set targetRange = Selection.Range

    '--- drop a bookmark to return the cursor to it's original location
    Const RETURN_BM = "OrigCursorLoc"
    myDoc.Bookmarks.Add Name:=RETURN_BM, Range:=Selection.Range

    '--- if nothing is selected, then search the whole document
    If Selection.Start = Selection.End Then
        Selection.Start = 0
        targetRange.Start = 0
        targetRange.End = myDoc.Range.End
    End If

    '--- build list of keywords to search
    Dim keywords() As String
    keywords = Split("basket case,binge,bipolar,black mark,black sheep,blackball,blacklist,blackmail,blind eye,blind spot,blindsided,boy,brainstorm,brave,brown bag,buffoonery,bugger,bum,bury the hatchet,cakewalk,call a spade a spade,cannibal,cat got your tongue,chief,chink,circle the wagons,climb the totem pole,colored people,crazy,cretin,crippled,drink the Kool-Aid,dumb,eenie meenie miney mo,eskimo,fallen on deaf ears,freeholder,fuzzy wuzzy,gangster,geronimo,ghetto,gip,grandfather clause,grandfathered,guru,gyp,gypped,handicapped,hip hip hooray,hold down the fort,homeless,homo,homosexual,hooligan,hysteria,illegal alien,indian giver,indian summer,inner city,lame,long time no see,low man on the totem pole,man hour,mankind,master,moron,mumbo jumbo,nazi,ninja,nitty gritty,no can do,off the reservation,on the warpath,paddy,peace pipe,peanut gallery,picnic,powwow,rain dance,red-headed stepchild,rule of thumb,sanity check,savage,scalp,sell someone down the river,shaman,sherpa,slave,sold down", ",", , vbTextCompare)

    '--- search for all keywords within the user selected range
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(keywords)
        '--- set the cursor back to the beginning of the
        '    originally selected range
        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=RETURN_BM
        Do
            With Selection.Find
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindStop
                .Text = keywords(i)
                .Execute

                If .Found Then
                    If (Selection.Start < targetRange.End) Then
                        Selection.Comments.Add Selection.Range, _
                                               Text:="Please consider using a different word or phrase as this may have a negative connotation."
                    Else
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            End With
        Loop
    Next i

    '--- set the cursor back to the beginning of the
    '    originally selected range
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=RETURN_BM
End Sub
```

I have not attempted to do anything yet.

Comment: `no longer lets me add more keywords` - what does it do instead?

Comment: Add some underscores to break up the line `keywords = Split("basket case,binge,bipolar,...", ",", , vbTextCompare)` into multiple lines: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/line-too-long

Answer (score 0):

It reachs the limit of max characters for a code line in VBE.

Please try. ***Note:*** `sKey1` should be ended with a comma.

```
    '--- build list of keywords to search
    Dim keywords() As String
    Dim sKey1 As String, sKey2 As String
    sKey1 = "one,two,three,"
    sKey2 = "basket case,binge,bipolar,black mark,black sheep,blackball,blacklist,blackmail,blind eye,blind spot,blindsided,boy,brainstorm,brave,brown bag,buffoonery,bugger,bum,bury the hatchet,cakewalk,call a spade a spade,cannibal,cat got your tongue,chief,chink,circle the wagons,climb the totem pole,colored people,crazy,cretin,crippled,drink the Kool-Aid,dumb,eenie meenie miney mo,eskimo,fallen on deaf ears,freeholder,fuzzy wuzzy,gangster,geronimo,ghetto,gip,grandfather clause,grandfathered,guru,gyp,gypped,handicapped,hip hip hooray,hold down the fort,homeless,homo,homosexual,hooligan,hysteria,illegal alien,indian giver,indian summer,inner city,lame,long time no see,low man on the totem pole,man hour,mankind,master,moron,mumbo jumbo,nazi,ninja,nitty gritty,no can do,off the reservation,on the warpath,paddy,peace pipe,peanut gallery,picnic,powwow,rain dance,red-headed stepchild,rule of thumb,sanity check,savage,scalp,sell someone down the river,shaman,sherpa,slave,sold down"
    keywords = Split(sKey1 & sKey2, ",", , vbTextCompare)
    Debug.Print UBound(keywords)
```

OR

```
    keywords = Split("one,two,three,basket case,binge,bipolar," & _
    "black mark,black sheep,blackball,blacklist,blackmail," & _
       ... other keywords ...
    "sold down", ",", , vbTextCompare)
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you so much for the quick response! Haha, seems like I have lots to learn since I didn't realize it was just a max character for a code line:)